# Could you install Ubuntu on an external hdd and run it on a Samsung smart TV?

Tags: smart-tv

I've got a Samsung Smart TV 4 series 32", and since the smart hub is pretty much useless, I wanted to know if there was a way to run Ubuntu from an external HDD on it.

Comment: I don't think so....

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use the [Ubuntu-Powered Intel Compute Stick](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/66521/20150706/ubuntu-powered-intel-compute-stick-go-sale-week-110.htm). It's processor, memory, SD slot and USB port that plugs into the HDMI input of anything that has an HDMI input.

If it proves to be useful, I'm sure it will only be the first available.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the technical specifications of the TV and except that it has a "dual core" processor there are no technical specifications on the processor architecture, and as it doesn't even allow Ubuntu to upgrade its firmware, I would say:

**"No, you cannot"**

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news …*

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**